# Find rails and their corresponding course using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a detection of LEGO City Rails to obtain if there is a curve and and whats the curve radius or angle.

As you can see I already cropped the picture. I also used different algorithms for edge detection like canny or just sobel operators.

[image: cropped Picture]

Unfortunately the railroad ties make it really hard to detect the curve properly. I already tried hough transform, but this doesn't work well. Also the OpenCV-function `cv2.findContours` doesn't work very well.

The following picture shows my current status which uses Canny Edge Detection. The red lines in the picture show the lines generated by the probablistic Hough-Transform. I already removed all horizontal lines and all lines with an angle smaller than 10 degree generated by the hough transform.

[image: hough transform]

Why doesn't the hough transform detect all lines in this picture?

Do you guys have any suggestions how I can detect the rails properly?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def empty(a):
    pass


path = 'media/SVIi0.png'
cv2.namedWindow("TrackBars")
cv2.resizeWindow("TrackBars",640,240)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Min","TrackBars",11,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Hue Max","TrackBars",66,179,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Min","TrackBars",0,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Sat Max","TrackBars",255,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Min","TrackBars",21,255,empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Val Max","TrackBars",255,255,empty)

while True:
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Min","TrackBars")
    h_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Hue Max", "TrackBars")
    s_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Sat Min", "TrackBars")
    s_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Sat Max", "TrackBars")
    v_min = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val Min", "TrackBars")
    v_max = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Val Max", "TrackBars")
    print(h_min,h_max,s_min,s_max,v_min,v_max)
    lower = np.array([h_min,s_min,v_min])
    upper = np.array([h_max,s_max,v_max])
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lower,upper)
    imgResult = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)


    cv2.imshow("Mask Images", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Original Images", img)

    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Just copy the above code a tracker will display line [image]then adjust the rail detection as per you requirement below are some example which i was able to achive compare the original[image] and adjusted image[image].

Comment: Thank you man, although that was not what i asked for, it helped me a lot!